# Get mic/webcam record stream using javascript/html5 only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ios, html, web-applications

I making a web application that need to record stream from the pc/mobile mic/camera using java script and html5(no flash). how i can do it?

Comment: are you asking what kind of libraries that you could use?

Comment: Yes, or maybe a API that i can use in pc/mobile devices for web applications

Comment: The user would need to confirm that action. Otherwise, it's a security hole.

Comment: no problem how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods, getusermedia and the legacy method using an input, which is what ios6 allows:

Old way:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

Current way:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

var video = document.querySelector('video');

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }, onFailSoHard);
} else {
  video.src = 'somevideo.webm'; // fallback.
}
```

These samples were copied from [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).  HTML5Rocks has many working samples as well.

Comment: ok, I am watching it work right now.  You should post your code and ask a specific question as to what is not working, and I will try to help you further.

Comment: can you post here the link to the website that do that?

Comment: Check if this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/embedded/result,js,html,css/presentation/) works for you.

Comment: I tried it, its only open my photo album, i need to get stream from mic/cam

Comment: The iPhone I was testing with left for the day, but the default browser for android allows the input method, and when I press 'choose file' it provides a dialog to browse for the file, and one of the choices is the webcam.  [Here](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/new-iphone-5-and-ios-6) a link with the updates to ios6.  If you scroll down to **IOS6 and HTML5 Development**, you can see that this is implimented.

Comment: I am testing the Fiddle I linked above on a new iPad running ios6, and when I press the `Choose File` button, I get a tooltip with options `Take Video` and `Choose Existing`.  When I select `Take Video`, it opens up the camera app, allows me to record video, and save it.  This may not be what you are looking for when it comes to streaming though, where the video is being placed in a video tag and broadcasted.  That is not possible in ios.

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.getUserMedia ( constraints, successCallback, errorCallback );
```

- [Short description with example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia)
- [API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html)
- [Supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/stream)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is no other way to get stream for webapp, sorry.